# What does "lifted you sanction to your account" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I got a message from a website:

> We already lifted you sanction to your account.

What does it mean?

Comment: You need to include full context. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance and edit your question.

Comment: You are unable to decipher its meaning because it's a poorly constructed, error-ridden sentence.

Comment: Sounds like your typical phishing mail.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the person who wrote it could barely speak English.  Assuming you have transcribed it accurately above you are strongly urged to suspect that it is "phishing" mail, as Sander suggests in his comment.

If you believe it MIGHT be real, and not phony, and you feel that further action is required, you should contact the institution directly -- **do not** reply using an address in the message and **do not** click on any "button" in the message.

If you made an error in transcription (ie, it really said "We *have* already lifted *the* sanction *on* your account") then disregard most of what I've said (though one should always suspect that an unsolicited message of this sort is phishing).

Comment: Heeey, you actually answered one, Licks.

Answer (score 0):

A "sanction" is a punishment.  Apparently, you did something that was against their policies and/or rules.  In relation to a website, a sanction is usually some kind of restriction that limits a user's permissions or abilities to use the site in order to dissuade you from doing what you did wrong again.  The message is saying that the punishment is now over and the restriction has been removed.  You are no longer being punished.  Your user account has returned to normal.